# Contour integration with polylogarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, polylogarithm

Starting from Bose-Einstein integral representation of the polylogarithm
$$Li_{s}(z) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{s-1}}{e^t/z - 1}dt \quad \quad(1)$$
it's not too hard to obtain the following contour integral:
$$Li_{s}(e^\mu) = -\frac{\Gamma(1-s)}{2\pi i}\oint_{H} \frac{(-t)^{s-1}}{e^{t-\mu} - 1}dt \quad \quad (2)$$
where $H$ is a Hankel contour ([derivation here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0701743.pdf)). Here we assume that $\mu$ does not lie on non-negative real axis.
Regarding (2), Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Integral_representations):

> The contour can be modified so that it encloses the poles of the integrand at $t − \mu = 2k \pi i$, and the integral can be evaluated as the sum of the residues
> $$Li_{s}(e^\mu) = \Gamma (1-s) \sum _{k=-\infty}^{\infty}(2k \pi i - \mu)^{s-1} \quad \quad (3)$$

I have the following picture in mind[image]
It's important to say here that I'm trying to obtain the formula for analytic continuation of polylogarithm, so initially I assume it's defined only in $|z|<1$ region.

Here's my question:
**what if I won't enclose *all* the poles?** Because it seems like I can make the RHS sum of (3) whatever I want, enclosing only first, say, 10 poles and then looping back.

Usually the contour is meticulously constructed to enclose the poles needed, but here we include the poles initially not present in it. Does it mean I can include any pole of any function in an arbitrary contour any time I want? I don't think so.

Thanks in advance! Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your contour is almost surely not the one implied: you can't move the contour through the poles without changing the value of the integral. I suggest you try the following: don't change the Hankel contour from $0$ to $\mu$ on the real line, and at the point $\mu$ rotate the upper half of the contour counterclockwise by $\pi/2$, and the lower half clockwise by $\pi/2$, semi-encircling the poles on the line $\text{Re}(z)=\mu$ from one side, from the right. Then use the semi-residue theorem. I am not sure if this is the way, but that's what I would try.